# Numpy invalid value encountered in scalar divide and overflow in exp

Tags: python, numpy, apple-m1, integer-overflow

Here is what I am trying to calculate:

```
    def attraction(b1, b2, b3):
        a1=10 * b1 + 20 * b2 + 6 * b3
        a2=12 * b1 + 18 * b2 + 10 * b3
        a3=0 * b1 + 10 * b2 + 30 * b3
        return a1, a2, a3

    def prob(a1, a2, a3, phi):
        de = np.exp(phi * (a1 - a2)) + 1 + np.exp(phi*(a3-a2))
        p1 = np.exp(phi * (a1 - a2)) / de
        p2 = 1 / de
        p3 = np.exp(phi * (a3 - a2)) / de
        return p1, p2, p3
```

`b1, b2, b3` are probabilities, so
`a1` is between `6` and `20`, `a2` is between `12` and `18`, `a3` is between `0` and `30`.
I am doing optimization, `phi` is a parameter to be estimated, and it does not have a bound, but it has never given me a value larger than 1 or smaller than 0.

I sometimes get

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp p3 = np.exp(phi * (a3 - a2)) / de

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in scalar divide p3 = np.exp(phi * (a3 - a2)) / de

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  de = np.exp(phi * (a1 - a2)) + 1 + np.exp(phi*(a3-a2))
```

I suppose this is not because `de` is zero, but because `de` is too large.
I have tried to set `float128` but I get error `TypeError: data type 'float128' not understood`. After some search, I suppose `float128` is not available in M1 mac.

My question is how to solve the problem without giving up precision.

Comment: Please post the code where you define the parameter values.

Comment: Are you sure about those limits for a1, a2, a3 and phi? The biggest term you are going to get is exp(30) and that shouldn’t overflow.

Comment: @lastchance exactly, that's why I am confused..

Comment: Where did the lamda come from? It stops p1, p2 and p3 adding up to 1 (and doesn’t correspond to your error message).

Comment: @lastchance yeah, sorry, I copied wrong version. It should be phi, which has been corrected.

Comment: @jasmine, can you supply us with the a1, a2, a3 and phi values for a "fail case". Better still, could you supply us with a minimum runnable code that reproduces your issues (even if only occasionally, for randomly-generated parameters).

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your function to use log sum rather than exponents. This [link](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/02/09/log-sum-exp/) gives some good examples and details the mathematical foundations.

From the article:

```
>>> x = np.array([1000, 1000, 1000])
>>> np.exp(x)
array([inf, inf, inf])
```

Even with exponents of 1000 the value will overflow. They then add a function:

```
def logsumexp(x):
    c = x.max()
    return c + np.log(np.sum(np.exp(x - c)))
```

Which allows you to calculate the exponents indirectly

```
>>> logsumexp(x)
1001.0986122886682
>>> np.exp(x - logsumexp(x))
array([0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333])
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this with values in the given ranges (perhaps `lamda` is extremely outsized or `nan`<sup>1</sup>?)
However, you may be able to solve this with SymPy as it can represent values with tunably-high accuracy and both works with and can step oustide NumPy's type restrictions! (**cough at a tremendous execution speed penalty)

Setup

```py
>>> from sympy import symbols, exp
>>> a1, a2, a3, phi = symbols("a1 a2 a3 phi")
>>> de = exp(phi * (a1 - a2)) + 1 + exp(phi*(a3-a2))
>>> p1 = exp(phi * (a1 - a2)) / de
>>> p1
exp(phi*(a1 - a2))/(exp(phi*(a1 - a2)) + exp(phi*(-a2 + a3)) + 1)
```

Lambdify to make a function which works with NumPy types

```py
>>> expr = lambdify((a1, a2, a3, phi), p1)
```

Give it a spin

```py
>>> a1_ = np.linspace( 6, 20, 20)
>>> a2_ = np.linspace(12, 18, 20)
>>> a3_ = np.linspace( 0, 30, 20)
>>> phx = np.linspace( 0,  1, 20)
>>> expr(a1=a1_, a2=a2_, a3=a3_, phi=phx)
array([3.33333333e-01, 3.22212128e-01, 2.97978285e-01, 2.70970702e-01,
       2.46581616e-01, 2.26688815e-01, 2.11128138e-01, 1.98368944e-01,
       1.85454387e-01, 1.67730136e-01, 1.40043425e-01, 1.01808120e-01,
       6.17809832e-02, 3.12962524e-02, 1.36403988e-02, 5.27442099e-03,
       1.84280490e-03, 5.86558449e-04, 1.70613612e-04, 4.53975898e-05])
```

Original function (note this doesn't reproduce, but I don't have an M1 arch system, nor `lamda`)

```
>>> lamda = 1
>>> prob(a1_, a2_, a3_, phx)[0]
array([3.33333333e-01, 3.22212128e-01, 2.97978285e-01, 2.70970702e-01,
       2.46581616e-01, 2.26688815e-01, 2.11128138e-01, 1.98368944e-01,
       1.85454387e-01, 1.67730136e-01, 1.40043425e-01, 1.01808120e-01,
       6.17809832e-02, 3.12962524e-02, 1.36403988e-02, 5.27442099e-03,
       1.84280490e-03, 5.86558449e-04, 1.70613612e-04, 4.53975898e-05])
```

---

SymPy can also simplify the expressions, but not much

```py
>>> p1.simplify()
exp(a1*phi)/(exp(a1*phi) + exp(a2*phi) + exp(a3*phi))
```

Some size demos

```py
>>> np.exp(1000)
inf
>>> sympy.exp(1000)
exp(1000)
>>> sympy.exp(1000).n()
1.97007111401705e+434
>>> exp(10**6) / pi
exp(1000000)/pi
>>> (exp(10**6) / pi).n()
9.65502447726994e+434293
>>> sympy.exp(1000).n() / np.arange(1,5)  # note 2
array([1.97007111401705e+434, 9.85035557008524e+433,
       6.56690371339016e+433, 4.92517778504262e+433], dtype=object)
```

footnotes

1. comment on Question about `de` resulting in/containing a `nan` removed
2. note the array contents here is *not* a proper numeric NumPy array, but contains ***objects***, which are a Python type and orders of magnitude less efficient to work with